# How can I pass arguments from view to controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, arguments

How can I pass arguments from view to controller?
Hi everybody! I'm working in project but I have a problem. 
I want to pass one argument from my view to my controller and after use this variable for get a result of my database.
my view:

```
<? $gCC = $this->getCustomer($gQ['id_u']);
foreach($gCC as $gC): ?>
Nombre<br />
Empresa<br />
<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> direccion@direccion.com
<? endforeach; ?>
```

my controller

```
$data['getCustomer'] = $this->generals->getCustomer($id);
```

I grateful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anchor` tag to pass `single` or `multiple` arguments in your view.

```
<a href="http://example.com?test=1">dummy_name</a>
```

You can get value of `test` parameters by `GET` method in your controller.

```
$this->input->get('test'); //gives you 1 in your controller
```

You can also pass the parameters by segments in view.

```
<a href="http://example.com/test_1/test_2/test_3/test_4">dummy_name</a>
```

You can get value by `URI` segments in your controller.

```
$this->uri->segment(1); //gives you test_1 in your controller
$this->uri->segment(2); //gives you test_2 in your controller
$this->uri->segment(3); //gives you test_3 in your controller
$this->uri->segment(4); //gives you test_4 in your controller
```